# Docker Node Module Error on Docker Run, but Not in Development Mode

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my Dockerfile configuration that is currently preventing me from running my image as a container. I have a NextJS application that runs fine in dev mode and when I build and run in production, as well as when I first set up the Docker image, but since I have made some changes and posted a new image, it fails with an error message tha appears to be related to the `bcrypt` library. It seems strange that there is a problem with this individual library given there is no issue with the dev environment which makes me believe it is a problem with my Dockerfile commands.

**Here is the error message:**

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1167
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Error loading shared library /usr/src/app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: Exec format error
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1167:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:828:14) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:alpine
# Setting working directory. All the paths will be relative to WORKDIR
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copying source files
COPY . .
# Build app
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

# Run the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Here are my dependencies within `package.json`:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-redis": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "next": "10.0.3",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.28.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "postcss": "^8.1.10",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the container?  Do you have Compose `volumes:` or `docker run -v` options that hide the `/usr/src/app` directory your Dockerfile builds, and if so, does removing these options help?

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze thanks for the comment and offer to help. A bit of a novice still with Docker so not certain the best way to check. I'm launching with `docker run -p 3000:3000 image-name`

Comment: Sorry not using Docker compose at the moment, but considering to do so